# Laravel query - whereIn orWhere combined

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a collection `Products` and

productVendors: `["ASICS TIGER","FLEX FIT"]`

productTypes: `["SHOES","T-SHIRTS"]`

productTags: `["autumn","cap"]`

I can easily write:

```
$products->whereIn('productVendors', ["ASICS TIGER","FLEX FIT"])
         ->whereIn('productTypes', ["SHOES","T-SHIRTS"])
         ->whereIn('productTags', ["autumn","cap"])->get();
```

but thats not what I need.

I need to get all products but like this `->whereIn('productVendors', ["ASICS TIGER","FLEX FIT"]) OR ->whereIn('productTypes', ["SHOES","T-SHIRTS"]) OR ->whereIn('productTags', ["autumn","cap"])->get();`

It Will be perfect if Laravel has query `orWhereIn` but don't :(

How I can build a query like that?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel have [orWhereIn](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereIn) , I dont konw why you think it doesn't have

```
$products->orWhereIn('productVendors', ["ASICS TIGER","FLEX FIT"])
         ->orWhereIn('productTypes', ["SHOES","T-SHIRTS"])
         ->orWhereIn('productTags', ["autumn","cap"])->get();
```

you can find the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) in **whereIn / whereNotIn / orWhereIn / orWhereNotIn** section.

Comment: What about version 5.8 ??

Comment: it also have :https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereIn